# Functions returning other functions

Tags: python-2.7, function

```
def compose_greet_func():
    def get_message():
        return "Hello there!"

    return get_message

greet = compose_greet_func()
greet()
```

Output:'Hello there!'

Hi There. I am new to coding. 
Could anyone please explain me the use of **greet()** in the above program. I mean how **greet()** is helping to get the output. Thanks a lot. P.S:Kindly do not downvote the question as I will be get blocked from asking any more. Thanks!!!

Comment: *Kindly do not downvote the question as I will be get blocked from asking any more* - that means you've been asking poor question that were not well received... thus asking for no downvotes is useless. *Ask a good question and you won't be downvoted*...

Comment: @AndrewLi I clearly understand that. I am trying my best, but never mind.

Comment: @AndrewLi I am a beginner, so its natural I may ask very simple questions. No two people see the things in the same way. I understand what you are saying, I will try to keep up.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this only outputs "Hello there!" when run in the shell:

[image]

Functions are just like any other `int`, `float`, `str`. They can be passed around and put into variables. The only difference is that functions can be called when you add `()` and put parameters in.

`compose_greet_func` returns `get_message`. What is `get_message`? It's a function that returns "Hello there!". Now you call:

```
greet = compose_greet_func()
```

`greet` now has the value of "a function that returns "Hello there!"". Since `greet` has the value of a function, you can call it by attaching `()` to the end of it:

```
greet()
```

In the shell, if you call a function that returns a value, the shell will print the return value. So that's why calling `greet()` gets you the output.